# How to get substrings without using substring() method in Java?

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm just looking for a simple way to be able to extract substrings without using the substring method.

Comment: treat the string like an array using `charAt` and extract it yourself.

Comment: You can always look into the source code of the substring method.

Comment: Can you add a code where you intend to extract the data or text without having to use substring() method. Of course there many ways you can implement your code but add what you have done or your approach here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "Hello World!";
        String newStr = "";
        int startFrom = 2, endBefore = 5;// test startFrom and endBefore indices
        for (int i = startFrom; i < endBefore; i++)
            newStr += String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
        System.out.println(newStr);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
llo
```

**[Update]**

Using `StringBuilder` has two obvious advantages:

1. You do not need to `String.valueOf` to convert the `char` value to `String` value before appending it to the string because [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(char)) supports appending a `char` value to it directly.
2. You can avoid the creation of a lot of `String` objects because since `String` is an immutable class, every attempt to change the string will create a new `String` object. You check a good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java).

   ```
   public class Test {
       public static void main(String args[]) {
           String str = "Hello World!";
           StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder();
           int startFrom = 2, endBefore = 5;// test startFrom and endBefore indices
           for (int i = startFrom; i < endBefore; i++)
               newStr.append(str.charAt(i));
           System.out.println(newStr);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: oh no, string concatenation in loop!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a homework question, but if you want a hint you can use `myString.toCharArray()` to extract a `char[]` of every character in the string and `myString.charAt(0)` to get a character at index 0 for example.

You can also construct a new String from a character array `new String(myCharArray)` thus you can trivially just

1. Take your original string and get a character array (`char[] myChars = myString.toCharArray();`, for example)
2. Copy the character array into a new, shorter one (`char[] mySubstringChars = ...`)
3. Change the shorter char array back into a String  (`String mySubstring = new String(mySubstringChars);`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a homework question, but we haven't learnt arrays, functions or other fancy stuff. We're as far as variable declaration and using simple string methods. I'm pretty sure you could make a function that does the job of the substring method, but as I said, I'm a complete beginner.